# How to get result in following scenario

Tags: sql, select, oracle10g, subquery, mssql-jdbc

I have table

```
EMP(id int primary key, name varchar2(15), mgrID int).
```

Now this table contain all employees(including worker and manager) in `company. mgrID` column contain  id of employee to whom they are reporting.

I want to list the name of worker who is not manager along with their name of manager.
What to do for such query.

I tried nested select query as follows:

```
select name, (select name from EMP where mgerID is NULL) 
as Manager from EMP;
```

Will this query give proper result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a self-join:

```
SELECT e.name AS name, m.name AS manager_name
FROM   emp e
JOIN   emp m ON e.mgrid = m.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should fail because you sub-query is uncorrelated and will return multiple results if you have multiple top-level managers.

```
select name
     , (select name from EMP b where b.ID = a.mgerID ) as Manager 
  from EMP a;
```

I think the self-join is the more canonical solution, but you should understand the correlated subquery as well as it has many application.